# how to escape mod_rewrite default encoding

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, escaping, cjk

I am writing some mod_rewrite rule for non-English sites. My URI (query) looks like `%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AB%E5%90%88%E8%A1%86%E5%9B%BD`, but when I get the request in the application running on Tomcat, all I get is "?????".

I'm unable to understand what kind of encoding Apache is doing over here. I tried the NE & B flags but in vain. Any suggestions?

The rewrite looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)$ /slice/index.html?reqURI=%{REQUEST_URI} [P,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you paste the cond/rules with the usage of the encode string, not an example with xyz? It appears those are chinese characters your encoding..

Comment: %E3%82%A2%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AB%E5%90%88%E8%A1%86%E5%9B%BD is the urlencoded value of  アメリカ合衆国 Japanese word.
The xyz part i dont have any issue with the host name:
eg: url is www.xyz.com/test/アメリカ合衆国

Comment: I googled around a bit and found [this page](http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/kieranshaw/entry/utf-8_internationalisation_with): "the characters get mangled as Apache tries to do some unescaping of its own into ISO-8859-1, but it's UTF-8 not ISO-8859-1 so it doesn't work properly. So, to keep our special characters in UTF-8, we'll escape it back again." `RewriteMap escape int:escape` `RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://mydomain:8080/filedownload/?filename=${escape:$1} [QSA,L,P]`.